# Consume WCF Service over named pipe hosted in WPF app from Windows Service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, named-pipes

I host a WCF Service in a WPF appilication which updates the GUI using a named pipe. In a Windows Service I consume this WCF-Service to update the GUI.

I host it in my WPF app with the following code:

```
private ServiceHost serviceHost;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        string address = "net.pipe://localhost/Path/ServiceName";
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ComGUIService));
        NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IComService), binding, address);
        serviceHost.Open();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: Logging & Handling
    }
}
```

And consume it in my Windows service:

```
string address = "net.pipe://localhost/Path/ServiceName";

NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(address);

IComService channel =
    ChannelFactory<IComService>.CreateChannel(
        binding, ep
    );

try
{
    channel.SendUpdatedStatus("test");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Throws: The pipe endpoint net.pipe://localhost/... could not be found on your local machine
}
```

> System.IO.PipeException: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/... that could accept the message

The strange thing is, the exact same code works when it is excecuted in a Console app and the communication to the WPF app is successfull. Is there something special about the communication between a Windows Service and a desktop app through named pipes? Is this even possible?

Comment: This is most like a security issue.  By default the user account a windows service runs under is LocalService which has few privileges and probably cannot connect a named pipe to anything.  Try starting the service under your own account and I think you will see it works.  Finding the appropriate account for a Windows service to run under must be carefully done or else you will open a security hole.

Comment: @AQuirky To except this issue I already run it with the same account I start the WPF app. No success.

Comment: Ok.  I coded up a Windows Service and a WPF client exactly as you have shown it here and it is working fine even under the default LocalService account.  So I have a feeling the problem is in the way you implemented the service. I did the absolute bare minimum: created service loop which was created on a new thread in OnStart.  The service loop after establishing a connection loops continuously with1 second delay sending "test" and it is all working fine.

Comment: @AQuirky Thank you very much for testing. Tomorrow I will try to setup a new service and start from scratch.

Comment: @AQuirky Unfortunately I had no luck. Have you created a ProjectInstaller for your service? What are your settings? What .NET version you are using?

Comment: Using .NET Framework 4.6.1.  No ProjectInstaller.  I simply used sc.exe to install the service and net start to start it.  Not sure anyone uses ProjectInstaller.  I use WIX for installers.

Comment: @AQuirky I managed to get it working. Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue going on. The problem is your service runs in session 0 when running as a service and your app in session 2. You see it working when running the service as a console, because both apps are running under the same session 2 (no additional perms needed). The named pipe has to be created in a shared memory space for the service to actually see the named pipe, and when they are running different sessions you will see this problem crop up. The solution is to simply allow "create Local Object" permission to the necessary users/groups. Go into group policy editor. Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> local Policies -> User Rights Assignments -> Create global objects (add user group to this permission and you should be good to go!). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. Before I can use this setting I have to double check if this policy is safe for the user group.

Comment: I understand. I'm dealing with a customer that is reluctant about that perm change so I'm looking at other options. One thing that also may work, which I haven't tried....I think if you connect your UI to your service(session 2 to session 0) you may not need this permission. If you want to "push" to your UI, just use duplex bindings and have your UI connect to the web service and and subscribe to callbacks. I haven't tried this yet so I'm not sure if this will work, but It may be a viable solution.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. The only thing I had to do was to run the WPF application with administrative privileges. Why the communication between those application only works when the WPF application is running as Administrator is still a mystery.

Comment: Well you have to give me a bit of credit.  My first comment to you was it was probably a security issue.  You can't give up now though!  My WPF app communicates fine without Admin and with my service running under the LocalService account.  What is worse than it not working is it working and opening a big hole in your security.